# Plot multiple obs. of 1 variables using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I a dataset whose matrix is delimited as follows `multiple obs. of 1 variables` :

```
>GC_percent
[1,] 0.4835822
[2,] 0.4782782
[...]
[5622,] 0.4968492
[5623,] 0.5076531
```

And I would draw a histogram with this one:

```
qplot(GC_percent, geom="histogram")
```

But inevitably it does not work:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix
```

Comment: ggplot2 expects a data.frame. Give it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roland said, ggplot2 needs a dataframe:

```
GC_percent <- as.data.frame(GC_percent)
qplot(GC_percent, geom="histogram")
```